# Magento 2 Import product are not updated in front

Tags: magento2.2, import, csv, reindex

I imported 1500 products from a CSV file that went well.
In the back office when I look at my individual product, the value of the attribute is good. However, when I look in the list of products still in the back office, the value of my attribute is not the same, it's still the same value before update. It is bad, and it is the same one that is visible on the front-end.

Of course, I emptied the cache and reindexed everything.

*I'm at a dead end...*

Comment: Can you check the store views if you have multiple stores and storeviews?

Comment: no, just one, simple default configuration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **change the scope to GLOBA**L and it works fine...

*I dont understand but ..problem cleared !*